# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number error

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm having a problem with my code, I've checked it multiple times but can't seem to locate it. I'm working with HTML, JS, Slim framework and PHP and getting my data from mysql. 
Any help would be appreciated!

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
    var coach=new Coach(
                        $("#CoachFirstName").val(),
                        $("#CoachLastName").val(),
                        $("#CoachExperienceYrs").val(),
                        $("#CoachPastTeam").val());



    $.ajax({
     type:'PUT',
     dataType:"json",
     url:"db.php/coachs/1",
     data:JSON.stringify(coach),
     success: showResponse,
     error: showError
        });    
    }); });

function Coach(CoachFirstName, CoachLastName, CoachExperienceYrs, CoachPastTeam){

        this.CoachFirstName=CoachFirstName; 
        this.CoachLastName=CoachLastName; 
        this.CoachExperienceYrs=CoachExperienceYrs;
        this.CoachPastTeam=CoachPastTeam; 
    }   function showResponse(responseData) { 
        console.log(responseData);      } 

            function showError() {          
         alert("Error while updating" );
         };
```

PHP - SLIM

```
 $app->put('/coachs/:id', 'updateCoach');


    function updateCoach($id){
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $coach = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "UPDATE coach SET CoachFirstName=:CoachFirstName, CoachLastName=:CoachLastName, CoachExperienceYrs=:CoachExperienceYrs, CoachPastTeam=:CoachPastTeam WHERE CoachID=:id";
    try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("CoachFirstName",$coach->CoachFirstName);
    $stmt->bindParam("CoachLastName",$coach->CoachLastName);
    $stmt->bindParam("CoachExperienceYrs",$coach->CoachExperienceYrs);
    $stmt->bindParam("CoachPastTeam",$coach->CoachPastTeam);
    $stmt->bindParam("id",$id); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $coach = $stmt->fetchObject();
    $db = null;
    responseJson(json_encode($coach),200);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    responseJson('{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}', 500);
}

    }
```

Comment: You have 6 placeholders, but only bind 5 values.

Comment: You miss to bind `TeamName`

Comment: Took it out as I don't need that but it still comes up with the same error :( @JonStirling@ @Jens

Comment: That's it there @JonStirling

Comment: Got it to work @JonStirling I removed $stmt->fetchObject(); and it solved the issue!!